# Chrome: recovering Chrome autofill data from a corrupt ex-Win10 PC

Tags: google-chrome, ssd, data-recovery

Can one run Chrome with a named profile from command line off a USB rescue media with W10, to rescue Chrome data from a corrupt SSD? Before you say that it's a ridiculous idea, please hear me out.

I have a corrupt-SSD Win 10 PC with Chrome (W10 and Chrome installed Aug 2021, with regular updates). Upon the most recent automated W10 update (Nov 15, 2023), Win 10 was never able to start: following the update the PC got stuck at "100% cleaning up" for 8 hrs, at which point I did a hard shutdown (surely 8 hrs was enough), upon which the PC never found Windows 10 on itself. Tried to repair and revert the updates from a rescue USB media, no luck (and no useful error messages).

I moved the entire contents of C: with robocopy onto another drive (it could not copy thousands files due to SSD errors, although I did not see any errors in system files). I have recovered all important data, except that I cannot remember several important passwords which were autofilled by Chrome in the old PC. These were not simple "forgot my password" cases. I then tried copying Chrome user data onto another PC, no luck. I then did a search here, and it looks like I cannot just move Chrome folders due to local data encryption by Chrome (tied to the machine).

Interestingly, the corrupt ex-Win10 PC still works... to an extent. E.g. I can still run regedit, Notepad, and Chrome from command line using the same Win 10 USB rescue media. Chrome seems to start with a "fresh" default profile I never used, and I can access its settings. I cannot get to my own data, b.c. I used to login from a named profile in Win10. Thus, I wonder if I can still run chrome from that named profile, and unlock the password DB from it (or at least synch the data) -- before reinstalling Win10. Thus, the question is -- how does one run Chrome with a named profile from command line? If this can be done, it could be of help to poor souls who are trying to recover their non-synched Chrome data.

I am getting an independent cloud password manager after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running Chrome on the old machine was not successful. What did work is to first backup the C drive to another machine, the perform the following steps:

- extract encrypted key from Local State file, decode the base64 encoding and print as hex string
- use [NirSoft DPAPI tool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dpapi_data_decryptor.html) to decrypt the key (needs Windows login password as well as Protect folders and Registry Hive folder from the broken machine that used to run Chrome)
- feed decrypted key into [this Python script](https://github.com/ohyicong/decrypt-chrome-passwords):  I had to replace their get_secret_key() method, set CHROME_PATH_LOCAL_STATE and CHROME_PATH to correct values for local backup
- Note: you can also modify this script to accomplish base64 decoding and hex printing by adding this line after the b64decode function is called:
  `print(" ".join(format(n, '02x') for n in secret_key))`
- run the script and enjoy decrypted passwords.

P.S. No, I did not figure this out; I happen to be married to a girl hacker. Maybe this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible since according to Google it is encrypted by a 'secret key known only to your device' [citation](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10311524?hl=en-GB#:%7E:text=When%20you%20use%20Chrome%20to%20sign%20in%20to,an%20obscured%20copy%20of%20your%20data%20to%20Google.). I asked chatgpt but it makes mistakes a lot so you'll have to accept that this method probably won't work but it's worth a try.
ChatGPT's response:

1. **Connect the SSD to Another System:**

   - Remove the SSD from the non-functional PC.
   - Connect it to another functional PC using an external USB enclosure, SATA-to-USB adapter, or by directly installing it in the second system.
2. **Recover Chrome User Data:**

   - Navigate to the user data directory of Chrome on the connected SSD. The default path is typically:

     ```
     C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\
     ```
   - Copy the entire "User Data" folder to a location on the second system.
3. **Accessing Passwords:**

   - On the second system, install Chrome if not already installed.
   - Copy the recovered "User Data" folder to the corresponding directory on the second system.
   - Open Chrome and your named profile should be available with saved passwords.

Remember, data recovery can be a complex process, and if the SSD is physically damaged or there are severe corruption issues, it may be necessary to consult with a professional data recovery service.

Always ensure you have a backup of critical data, and consider using cloud-based services or external drives for important information in the future.

Also, the password manager I recommend is Bitwarden, it's free, very secure and I use it. (I wrote this, not chatGPT.

Comment: Duplicake: regarding this: " 'secret key known only to your device'" -- this is exactly why I am trying to run chrome from command line from the very same (corrupt, but still showing residual signs of life) PC. I already tried the ChatGPT solutions -- not that I used ChatGPT...